# SUPEE_7405 not getting installed on magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, php, security, patches

I have successfully installed following patches

5344

5944

6237

6788

for **Magento 1.9.1.0.** Now for **SUPEE_7405** I am getting this error

```
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php

Hunk #1 FAILED at 171.

Hunk #2 succeeded at 182 (offset -10 lines).

1 out of 2 hunks FAILED
```

Answer (score 1):

The list of needed patches (from latest to oldest) is:

- SUPEE-8788
- SUPEE-7405
- SUPEE-6788 installed
- SUPEE-6482 missing
- SUPEE-6285 missing
- SUPEE-5994 done
- SUPEE-5344 done

So maybe you try to revert 6788, then install 6285 and 6482 and then re-apply 6788 and 7405 again. The patches need to be installed in the correct order.

SUPEE-6237 which you installed is not a security, but a USPS patch.

Comment: Are you sure 6285 and 6482 are applicable for version 1.9.1.0 ?

Comment: It is for 1.9.2 and above  https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6285

Comment: 6285 was fixed in CE 1.9.2.0 so it is needed in versions below 1.9.2.

Comment: 6482 is needed as well for 1.9.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have changed this file

follow below steps :

> 1) copy this file in local code pool
>
> 2) replace this file from fresh magento same version as yours current version

and after that apply that patch again.

Comment: Not working yet. I have copied fresh file from Magento stock 1.9.1.0. But still getting same error.